# Limited Access Permissions applied to all

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions

I am experiencing some issues with permissions. One of our project managers is unable to load the hillbillytabs javascript that runs our project dashboard (`JS file is stored in siteAssets`).

I went to the developer tools to check the actual error and it says:

```
"Refused to execute script from: siteAssets/hillbillytabs… because its MIME type('text/HTML') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."
```

After looking into the error some say it is due to permissions.

Well, let's take a look at our permissions. My best guess is that this has something to do with the permission group "`style resourced readers`".

If I enter the permissions group, it basically says everyone has limited access... could this be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this issue for specific users or all users ? also make sure that this file is checked in as published as amain version

Comment: What are the permissions on the Site Assets library for the Style Resource Readers group? If non existent, give them read and try again. Does this user have any other permission or is he granted access solely from the style resource reader group?

Comment: this is an issue with a few specific users. As a power user, I can see the tabs, but one of our project managers is unable to see it. Our site collection admin can see it as well. I gave the Project manager access to one of our groups that has read access. She is auto added to the style resource reader group

Comment: also, i went to the "shared with" button in the ribbon for siteAssets, the user in question has access according to this